# Laravel Update Request MethodNotAllowedException

Tags: php, laravel

I have a class called CustomerController with an Update function:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
//use app\model\Customer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\model\Customer;

class CustomerController extends Controller
{
   public function getAllCustomer()
   {
       return Customer::get();
   }

public function addNewCustomer(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'Title' => 'required',
        'Name' => 'required|max:255',
        'Surname' => 'required|max:255',
        'Email' => 'required',
        'Phone' => 'required',
        'Password' => 'required',
        'dateofBirth' => 'required'
    ]);

    return \app\model\Customer::create($request->all());
}


public function update (Request $request , Customer $id)
{
    $id->update($request->all());
}
```

This is the route:

```
Route::put('Customer/{id}' , 'CustomerController@update');
```

But currently Im getting a MethodNotAllowedException, I couldnt find any solution.
A screenshot:
[image]
Thank you very much!

Route does exist:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to `php artisan route:list` to see if that route is available? (Caching!!!). Or `php artisan route:cache` to clear and cache the routes?!

Comment: @Kerbholz Yes it does exist, added a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When updating, therefore using the PUT method, you must have a hidden input in your form like the below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

the form will still be a post

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
```

Or as mentioned by @kerbholz (many thanks) you can use the helper

```
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

Comment: Or use `{{ method_field('PUT') }}` in your Blade. From [Laravel Helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-method-field)

Comment: Oh never knew about that, many thanks. Added it to my answer with your credit

Comment: Thx, no problem Btw, it's `PUT`, not `DELETE` ;)

Comment: Hasn't got anything to do with your URI being an uppercase C for customer as none of your other routes follow that?

Comment: Thank you, I didnt see that, now postman tells me that the page has expired due to inactivity (error 419).

Comment: No problem, mind marking my question as correct if it's helped

Comment: Sure, it helped me, but Im still getting the error 419, do you have any tips?

Comment: http://getstatuscode.com/419 make sure your auth is functioning correctly and Postman is sending a valid token

Comment: Thank you very much, I needed to put an except on VerifiedCsrfToken, now I dont get an error, but it's actually not updating, nothing happens

Comment: Do you know how to put Parameters into postman? I thought i needed to to this in the Body, for example :                                                                                      {
 "name": "Hans"
}

Answer (score 0):

change you route method with both put and patch

The main reason you're getting this error is that your form submit method is different with your route method.

```
Route::match(['put', 'patch'], '/Customer/{id}','CustomerController@update');
```